# How to destroy a filesystem

Tags: filesystems

We have some USB storage devices were the filesystem is corrupted (RAW). We don't really know the exact reason, so I would like to simulate the problem. Are there any tools or methods to destroy the filesystem. Or better yet, are there any guidelines on how NOT to destroy the filesystem.

thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achive by destroying the file system manually. If you want to figure out how the filesystem got corrupted you will have to try all the things that where done with the device and check wether or not it has been corputed in the mean time.

Answer (score 4):

There are scenarios in which shred may not work with all the file systems.
One alternative apart from shred is to dd the whole partition itself.

Assuming your device is /dev/sdb or something like that , you can  dd the whole partition using the following command ,

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

This should overwrite all the contents of partitions including the data structures(super blocks etc) of the previous file system with zero , effectively killing the file system for you.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to a Linux system, you can use [`shred`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shred_%28Unix%29).

Insert the USB Storage, execute `dmesg | tail` to get the name of the created device (if the computer you use has only one HD it is probably `/dev/sdb`), then execute the following command as root or with `sudo` (replace `/dev/sdX` with the actual device):

```
shred /dev/sdX
```

If your usb device has multiple partitions you can execute `shred` on a single partition instead of the whole device if you give it the appropriate device file handle (e.g. `/dev/sdb1`).

`shred` works by overwriting the specified file (or in this case the whole partition or device) multiple times with random data - if your USB Storage is large, this can take a very long time.

Comment: ... and if you don't have Linux, download, say, Ubuntu and boot it from a DVD or a flash drive: no installation required.